# Where is the best place to put "[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver"

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I get used to put "[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver" in init method. And I have seen a lot of others put in viewDidLoad. Is there any instruction or best practice on it?

Liang

Comment: Use it where you need it. Generally speaking, if your view(controller) isn't visible, you shouldn't be listening for events from other objects.

Comment: I prefer doing it in init and then remove the observer in dealloc. In our case, we do want our viewControllers to get notified of certain events even when the view isn't showing, so when the view does show the data is already present.

Comment: I Think the best in the **viewDidLoad** and remove the observer in the **viewDidDisappear**

Comment: @EricS By putting it in the class initialiser how do you deal with the issue of notifications being fired and received before the view had loaded where you might need to update the UI?

Comment: We check viewController.isViewLoaded to see if the view has been loaded. If not, we just store away the information for when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it honestly doesn't really matter. My opinion is that it's best in the viewDidLoad, but like @EricS said, if you want to get notified when the view isn't showing then that won't exactly work. So it really just depends on how you prefer to use it and when you want to be notified of those events

Answer (score 0):

Two questions to ask yourself:

1. Can this notification be fired between when the UIViewController is init'ed and when its view is loaded?
2. If the notification can be fired between those events, does it matter to your UIViewController's state?

These questions will guide you towards which method to call addObserver within. There's no particular "best practice" other than this:

*Only listen when you need to.*